# Downloading tweets with twitteR does not work as hoped

Tags: r, twitter

I'm fairly new to R, I use it for a course on network analysis at my university.
As part of a research project, I want to analyse tweets by Donald Trump and Hillary Clinton. I successfully managed to grant RStudio access to my twitter account, but every time I try to download tweets, I get a fairly meager selection ranging from 1,100 tweets at best to just 800-900 tweets at worst. I do not understand this as I do not get any error message, either. Am I missing something? I thought the limit on downloading tweets was at 3,200?

This is my code:

```
#load twittR package and necessary tool for login
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
#load login data
api_key <- "blah"
api_secret <- "blah"
access_token <- "blah"
access_token_secret <- "blah"
#login
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
#retreive tweets by Donald Trump, maximum number is 3200
tweetsTrump <- userTimeline("realDonaldTrump", n=3200)
#convert those tweets to a dataframe
Trump.df <- twListToDF(tweetsTrump)
```

I am eternally grateful for every useful tip!

Comment: As mentioned in numerous similar questions: _"The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days."_. It's not an archive for all tweets that everyone can query as he or she wishes...

Comment: @lukeA, I'd add that as an answer. I can't seem to find any examples in R to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @sebastian-c Hm I found e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052811/twitter-searchtwitter-only-returns-a-small-set-of-tweets via https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+"searchTwitter"

Comment: `searchTwitter` functions differently than `userTimeline`, and going past 7 days is doable with `userTimeline` so both the question and answer are different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) where it says:

> The Twitter Search API searches against a **sampling** of **recent Tweets**
>   published in the past 7 days.
>
> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is
>   focused on **relevance and not completeness**. This means that some Tweets
>   and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for
>   completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

Thus, the results from the API are limited per se. If you want more, use the streaming api or services like [Gnip](https://gnip.com).

Comment: Thats the search api, what he's talking about is slightly different which is getting tweets from a specific user, which is possible to go back more than 7 days.

Comment: Good point. Then we are [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline), API-wise. I dunno why the API returns less then 3200. But it seems you get the 3200 by paginating through the history using the `maxID` parameter.

Comment: Yeah... When ive done it before i only cared about last 100 tweets, so i didn't bother with pagination, But it could be that the [api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) says that even if retweets and replies are excluded, they are excluded after the api uses your `count` parameter to pull all the tweets it can. [twitteR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) has `include` retweets set to `FALSE`.